# Is it possible to run scripts on the machine that is hosting an AWS Amplify web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm planning on hosting my web app on AWS Amplify as it is the backend I'm using. But I need an API running with Node.JS which
communicates internally on the machine with the web app. Only the machine can communicate with this API. Is this possible with AWS Amplify?

The only script I need to run is to install Node.JS and get the API up and running.

Comment: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/node-api/q/platform/js/